# Specific regular expression for java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to upload a file with a specific structure and I need to validate each line.
I think a regular expression would help but I'm not sure how to construct that

each line contains the next structure

```
decimalNumber : (1 to 15) of "(number,decimalNumber,$decimalNumber")
```

example

```
13.1 : (1,3.0,$100.23) (2,9.5,$21.3)
```

I want to validate also that the part after the colon doesn't contain more of 15 repetitions

Comment: Did you try something already? https://regex101.com/ has a nice guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^\d+\.\d+\s\:(\s\((1[0-5]|\d),\d+\.\d+,\$\d+\.\d+\)){1,15}$
```

- `\d+\.\d+` one or more digits followed by a literal `.` followed by one ore more digits
- `\s` some space
- `\:` a literal colon
- `\s` more space
- `( … ){1,15}` Then the following structure 1 to 15 times:

  - `\(` A left paren literal
  - `( … | … )` Next, an alternation. Either of the following:

    - `1[0-5]` a 1 immediately followed by a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5
    - `\d` a single digit
  - `,` A literal comma
  - `d+\.\d+` one or more digits followed by a literal `.` followed by one ore more digits
  - `,` A literal comma
  - `\$` A literal dollar sign
  - `\d+\.\d+` one or more digits followed by a literal `.` followed by one ore more digits
  - `\)` A right paren literal

https://regex101.com/r/I6Irrf/1/

Comment: it is correct except one unneeded ) after `[0-5]` - fixed is: `^\d+\.\d+\s\:(\s\((1[0-5]|\d),\d+\.\d+,\$\d+\.\d+\)){1,15}$` or in java code: `line.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\s\\:(\\s\\((1[0-5]|\\d),\\d+\\.\\d+,\\$\\d+\\.\\d+\\)){1,15}$")`